# Removing 'Sites' from Django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

The Django admin page has 'Sites' as a default object.

This is confusing to users, as my application also has a 'Site' model accessible through the admin page.

How can I remove the default object from the page?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

use [**`unregister`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.1/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L136):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

admin.site.unregister(Site)
```

I usually put this after the:

```
admin.autodiscover()
```

in urls.py

Comment: Much better is uncomment django.contrib.sites from the INSTALLED_APPS as recommends kovshenin.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps commenting out `django.contrib.sites` from the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in your settings.py file will help.

Comment: after syncdb this will cause an error and your app will not get up

Comment: @user35186 this is incorrect!.. if the "Sites" module is not used, this error will not manifest itself!

Comment: This option did not work for me either. If the sites module was installed already this will give an error. Not for existing sites.