# How to bypass django admin index and go to a specific application page?

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a Django project with only one app.

I don't need the site admin (same as my app admin), so I would like to bypass the site admin and go directly to my app admin, i.e. go directly to `mysite/admin/myapp/`  after loging in and removing `Home` in the breadcrumb.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is override the admin index page to redirect to app specific admin page.

As stated by @FallenAngel, you need to update the urls.py to have your view for admin index page. That view can redirect to inner app admin page.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core import urlresolvers
def home(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('admin:app_list', args=("myapp",)))
```

Answer (score 4):

`Django Url Dispatcher` scans all defined url definitions and redirect the request to the first matching url definition. At this point, url ordering is important, in `urls.py` file of your project root:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',   
    ...
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
)
```

You can define an url redirection form the *admin index page* url to a custom view

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',   
    ...
    (r'^admin/$', 'myapp.views.home'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
)
```

So, if the request url is your *admin index page*, then your custom view will be called, if it is an admin page (that starts with `admin/`) but not *admin index page*, then `admin.site.urls` will be executed...

in your `myapp.views` write a simple redirection view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/myapp/")
```

Comment: It redirects everytime you access admin panel. How to access other apps with keeping only login redirection?

Comment: `admin/$` will go to `myapp.views.home` only will be executed if address is `<your_site_address>/admin/` (`$` means end of text in regex and url dispatcher acepts regex addresses.) So if you go any address that starts with admin but continues with something else ( like `<your_site_address>/admin/blah`) will skip the match above and will match `(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`

Answer (score 1):

You can comment it out in the `INSTALLED_APPS` if you don't want that in your project. Just to remove it from admin you need to unregister. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742279/removing-sites-from-django-admin-page).

Another hack is, you can override the admin url `mysite/admin/` to simply redirect to  `mysite/admin/myapp/` in which you don't need to define your own redirect view. Django [DRY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) rocks there. :)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^mysite/admin/$', lambda x: HttpResponseRedirect('/mysite/admin/myapp/')),
                       url(r'^mysite/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                      )
```

For more customization you need to change the admin index page by customizing the admin templates. Doc is here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-index-page

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and easiest way is to use the generic `RedirectView` in `urls.py`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('admin:app_list',
        args=('myapp',)))),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: What if user want to go back to home page? This redirects to app urls everytime. How to access other apps while keeping this option.

Comment: What do you think?