# Unregistering a third-party ModelAdmin in Django causes NotRegistered error

Tags: python, django, admin

I want to completely hide a model from a third-party module (`otherapp`) in admin site.

I put `admin.site.unregister(ModelToHide)` in one of my apps' admin (`myapp`), but it causes `NotRegistered` error on every page. The problem is that `myapp.admin` is loaded *before* `otherapp.admin`.

I tried to change the order `INSTALLED_APPS` so that `otherapp` comes before `myapp`, but it did not help, Django loads them in reverse order. I read in one of the SO comments that order of `INSTALLED_APPS` does not matter, as per Django book.

Actually, I created this question just to share the way I made it work for me, because it took some time to figure out the solution. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Put `admin.site.unregister(ModelToHide)` just after `admin.autodiscover()` in urls.py so that it runs after all models have been registered.
2. Add an import to `myapp.admin`: `import otherapp.admin` so that it's loaded first.

Inspired by [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742402/304209) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571960/how-can-i-disable-the-django-celery-admin-modules#comment37479392_10573827).