# How to add extra validation to Waffle App in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using Waffle App in Django to use FeatureFlags. In the admin panel form for Waffle Flags, I'd like to force users to always add a description in the "Note" field, which is by default allowed to be left blank.

I think I can do this using a [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/forms/validation/) probably creating a clean_note() function, that I should add to the corresponding FormView.

Not sure where/how I should do that. Has anyone done something similar before?

Comment: You are talking about the admin panel form to add a new waffle, right?

Comment: Correct @SachinKukreja , updated the question in that respect to be more clear, thanks.

Comment: [Unregister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29502726/5312750) the `Flag` class. Create your own with the custom form.